# Passing javascript variable to VB.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have the code needed to pass a variable from javascript to vb.net, but it is not working for some reason and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the code. Please help. I declared a hidden variable and it stores the value and is then posted back, but the variable in the codebehind file is always empty.

Aspx code (**EDITED:**)

```
            <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>

            <%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" tagprefix="telerik" %>

            <!DOCTYPE html>

            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head runat="server">
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                           <asp:HiddenField ID="nwLatHidden" runat="server" Value="" />
                           <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
                               <Scripts>
                                   <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js">
                                   </asp:ScriptReference>
                                   <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js">
                                   </asp:ScriptReference>
                                   <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js">
                                   </asp:ScriptReference>
                               </Scripts>
                           </telerik:RadScriptManager>
                           <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
                           </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
                           <telerik:RadHtmlChart runat="server" ID="RadHtmlChart1">
                                <Legend>
                                    <Appearance Position="Bottom">
                                        <TextStyle FontSize="14" Color="Blue" FontFamily="Courier New, sans-serif" />
                                    </Appearance>
                                </Legend>
                                <PlotArea>
                                    <XAxis>
                                        <Items>
                                            <telerik:AxisItem LabelText="KM41872"/>
                                            <telerik:AxisItem LabelText="KM41873"/>
                                            <telerik:AxisItem LabelText="KM41871"/>
                                        </Items>
                                        <MajorGridLines Visible="false" />
                                        <MinorGridLines Visible="false" />
                                    </XAxis>
                                    <YAxis>
                                        <MinorGridLines Visible="false" />
                                    </YAxis>
                                    <Series>
                                        <telerik:LineSeries Name="Mean">
                                            <SeriesItems>
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.59" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.63" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.6" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.65" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.64" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.63" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.65" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.67" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.63" />
                                            </SeriesItems>
                                        </telerik:LineSeries>
                                        <telerik:LineSeries Name="Min">
                                            <SeriesItems>
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.55" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.56" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.55" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.61" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.56" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.57" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.59" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.61" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.55" />
                                            </SeriesItems>
                                        </telerik:LineSeries>
                                        <telerik:LineSeries Name="Max">
                                            <SeriesItems>
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.66" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.74" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.66" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.71" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.72" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.73" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.71" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.74" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.71" />
                                            </SeriesItems>
                                        </telerik:LineSeries>
                                    </Series>
                                </PlotArea>
                            </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    document.getElementById('nwLatHidden').value = '6.00';
                </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Codebehind:
    Public Class WebForm1
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            Dim nwLat As String
            nwLat = nwLatHidden.Value.ToString


    End Sub

    End Class
```

Comment: Read these articles to [learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), so you can provider more useful context information (and help yourself). Then you would find that you get an error like "Can't access property value of null".

Comment: I don't think my DOM doesnt exist, I am simply passing a constant, not searching the DOM

Comment: You are executing `document.getElementById('nwLatHidden')` before the element appears in the document. You can't get a reference to an element that doesn't exist yet. `getElementById` *does search* the DOM for an element with that ID (albeit in a very efficient manner).

Comment: oh ok, sorry, I am really new to javascript, I will double check. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I have moved the script code down before the body tag

Comment: it is still empty for some reason....

Comment: Do a view source and check the ID of your hidden field. The .NET ID isn't always the same as the id in the compiled html version of the page.

Answer (score 0):

try this

document.getElementById('<%=nwLatHidden.clientID').value = '6.00';